# How to get Youtube API subcategories of music like electronic, rock, instrumental etc

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have found the categories for music, sports etc but cannot find subcategories inside them. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any documentations or tutorial regarding subcategories for music category. I only read about the youtube api video category id list which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/dgp/1b24bf2961521bd75d6c). This [GitHub thread](https://github.com/google/shipshape/issues/115) also stated that this is not yet supported since some of the analysis tools do not make the subcategories easy to determine and there are others that create the subcategory dynamically. However, you can file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)) about this.

Comment: Thank you @abielita for your beautiful answer. I was confused whether there was feature to get subcatagories or not. You cleared my confusions

Answer (score 0):

The API only has categories, not subcategories. 
See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories

Comment: There is only the catagoires section to request but no subcatagories